# openmeap ant build command issue

Tags: ant

I have deployed OpenMEAP on Amazon AWS and OpenShift to get setup and running quickly. I now want to setup the local development environment so I can create a RESTful service to run on the OpenMEAP server and I have issues running the ant build commands. I keep getting unknown command on my Mac terminal when I run ant dist-all-web.

Answer (score 1):

After you installed Apache Ant from the link below, did you setup your Path and Env variables as stated in the install.txt? See below for Path & Environment Variables to setup on your Mac.

OpenMEAP command-line requires Apache Ant 1.8 or greater.
 http://ant.apache.org/

Path & Environment Variables - Mac

Set OpenMEAP Home Path
     export -x OPENMEAP_HOME=/Applications/OpenMEAP

Add the new version of Ant to current terminal session
     export PATH=/usr/local/apache-ant/bin:"$PATH"

Add the new version of Ant to future terminal sessions
     echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/apache-ant/bin:"$PATH"' >> ~/.profile

Verify that ANT and Java are installed
    Open your command-line tool and type ant -v and java -version

Comment: That did the trick. Can someone add an OpenMEAP tag? I would rather use Stack Overflow vs the OpenMEAP forum.